# Simple XAML-only Animation to Change Image Opacity on Button Click

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to create a simple animation example on the Windows Phone 8, but I imagine this should apply for WPF, WinRT, etc. anywhere XAML is used.

How do you animate the opacity of an  to change from 0 to 1 when a 's click event is fired?

I've seen many examples of animations, but the button is always animating it's own properties, not the properties of a different control.  I know I'm missing something small but I'm stumped -- no matter what I try I get XAML parse exceptions.  I can get this to work with C#, but not with XAML.

Comment: This would help you. It did for me. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: learn basics of expression blend and you will never write xaml for animations again:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is  easy way to handle storyboard animation on any component and control by another component

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263220.aspx